# How to convert bandwidth from wavelength to energy?

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, x-rays

I have an x-ray emission spectrum obtained using wavelength dispersive spectroscopy (WDS), the spectrum gives us the number of counts (intensity) as a function of wavelength. I measured the bandwidth (FWHM) in that case it gave me about 1.3 nm, my question is how can I convert the bandwidth from the wavelength unit into energy (eV)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an x-ray emission spectrum obtained using wavelength dispersive spectroscopy (WDS), the spectrum gives us the number of counts (intensity) as a function of wavelength.

The spectrum as a function of wavelength is integrated over wavelength to get counts:
$$
I = \int d\lambda f(\lambda)\;,
$$
where you might also denote $f(\lambda)$ as $\frac{dI}{d\lambda}$

> I measured the bandwidth (FWHM) in that case it gave me about 1.3 nm,

Here, you are saying there are some limits of integration:
$$
I_{FWHM} = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} d\lambda f(\lambda)\;,
$$
where $\lambda_2 - \lambda_1 = 1.3$nm.

> my question is how can I convert the bandwidth from the wavelength unit into energy (eV)?

The integral can be re-written as an integral over energy:
$$
I_{FWHM} = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} d\lambda f(\lambda)
= \int_{E(\lambda_1)}^{E(\lambda_2)} dE \frac{d\lambda}{dE} f(\lambda(E))\;,
$$
where $\lambda_2 > \lambda_1$ and where typically for a photon one will take:
$$
E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}\to \frac{d\lambda}{dE} = -\frac{hc}{E^2}\;.
$$

So, we can write:
$$
I_{FWHM} 
= \int_{E(\lambda_1)}^{E(\lambda_2)} dE \frac{d\lambda}{dE} f(\lambda(E))
= -\int_{hc/\lambda_1}^{hc/\lambda_2} dE \frac{hc}{E^2}f(\lambda(E))
= \int_{hc/\lambda_2}^{hc/\lambda_1} dE \frac{hc}{E^2}f(\lambda(E))\;,
$$
so the FWHM bandwidth in terms of energy is:
$$
\Delta E_{FWHM} = hc\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\lambda_2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way is to determine the wavelengths $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ on either side of your peak $\Delta\lambda$, convert each of those to energy via $E=hc/\lambda$, then compute $\Delta E$.

For small $\Delta\lambda$, it is also approximately true that:

$$\frac{\Delta\lambda}{\lambda_0}\approx\frac{\Delta E}{E_0}  $$

where $\lambda_0$ and $E_0$ are the center points of your peak.